# In Android, what thread is runnable passed to Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor running on?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency

In Android, what thread is runnable passed to [ScheduledExecutorService#schedule(Runnable command, long delay, TimeUnit unit)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#schedule(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) returned from [Executors#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()) running on?

As for my effort, I run this code:

```
        final ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        ses.schedule(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                inflate.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
            }
        }, 200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        ses.shutdown();
```

on Moto G 2013, Android 5.0.2, and setBackgroundDrawable operation works fine, means it ran on main (UI) thread.

Specifically, is this true for all android versions and devices? the linked javadoc pages states nothing about it. I want to avoid gotchas like, the service could spawn a new single thread to run the operation.

Comment: If you want the Runnable to be run on the UI thread, why do you use the ScheduledExecutorService at all?

Comment: i want to run that on ui thread but with delay.. what option do you suggest for this kind of task? I can't invoke something like `inflate.postDelayed()` because I am assuming this piece of code can run before the layout inflation process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new `Thread` (of the same `ThreadGroup`) will be created when calling `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()`. The implicitly used `DefaultThreadFactory` looks like that

```
static class DefaultThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
   private static final AtomicInteger poolNumber = new AtomicInteger(1);
   private final ThreadGroup group;
   private final AtomicInteger threadNumber = new AtomicInteger(1);
   private final String namePrefix;

   DefaultThreadFactory() {
       SecurityManager s = System.getSecurityManager();
       group = (s != null)? s.getThreadGroup() :
                            Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup();
       namePrefix = "pool-" +
                     poolNumber.getAndIncrement() +
                    "-thread-";
   }

   public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
       Thread t = new Thread(group, r,
                             namePrefix + threadNumber.getAndIncrement(),
                             0);
       if (t.isDaemon())
           t.setDaemon(false);
       if (t.getPriority() != Thread.NORM_PRIORITY)
           t.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);
       return t;
   }
}
```

If you want to reuse the UI-Thread you should write your own `ThreadFactory` returning the UI-Thread and call `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(yourNewlyCreatedThreadFactory)`

Comment: hmm, does this mean that other thread can do ui operations as long as they are in the same `ThreadGroup`? oh and I will follow your suggestion, my own `ThreadFactory` sounds safer.